# Exception - Call to undefined function course_overviewfiles_options()

Tags: moodle, php-7.1

I am using a Moodle(3.2.2 the newest one) site created by php7.0 and mysql5.7,but when i try to add a new course as administrator, an error called :Exception - Call to undefined function course_overviewfiles_options(). What can i do to fix it?
I did 'Purge all caches' from Development,so the problem above disappeared,but
when users login, another error occurred: Exception - Call to undefined function core_login_get_return_url(). 
I did 'Purge all caches'again, the problem no.2 disappeared and the no.1 occurred again.

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace (if you have one)?

Comment: Can you share the code involved? If you are using a stock version of Moodle (without any modifications), please open a bug report with them to resolve the problem properly

Answer (score -1):

You may have to include the correct library resource file:

```
require_once($CFG->libdir. '/coursecatlib.php');
```

Comment: note that if you think a question needs more details, you are discouraged from answering it. see [answer].

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely the case for you: `require_once('lib.php');`

Do it everywhere: `require_once('./lib.php');`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What do you mean by "everywhere"? Why should this change resolve the problem properly? If the file would not have been found, the error message would read different